# Disable reset button on Cisco 2950?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

On the front panel of a Cisco 2950 is a button which can be used to reset the switch to factory defaults, when held down for a few seconds.

Does anyone know of a way to disable this within IOS?

Many thanks!

Comment: Ironically this question just got answered on SF a few weeks ago... http://serverfault.com/questions/644037/cisco-catalyst-3750-disable-factory-default-reset-with-button-press

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable this feature using:

```
no setup express
```

To quote [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12-1_19_ea1/command/reference/2950cr/cli2.html#wp3550000):

> The primary purpose of the `no setup express` command is to prevent
>   someone from deleting the switch configuration by pressing the Mode
>   button for 10 seconds.